# In one query, get length of last name, length of first name and group by lengths - three columns

Tags: sql, oracle18c

I'm a noob...and working on a homework problem.

Have a members table with last_name, first_name. I want to write one query that aggregates the length of last_name, first_name by string length.

The output would have three columns - name_length, count_of_last_names, count_of_first_names.

Two individual queries:

```
`SELECT LENGTH(last_name) AS "LnameLen", COUNT(LENGTH(last_name)) AS "CntLnameLen"
FROM members
GROUP BY LENGTH(last_name)
ORDER BY "LnameLen" DESC;

SELECT LENGTH(first_name) AS "FnameLen", COUNT(LENGTH(first_name)) AS "CntFnameLen"
FROM members
GROUP BY LENGTH(first_name)
ORDER BY "FnameLen";`
```

But I want to write *one* query that outputs what the above two queries do, so the output would be three columns: Length_of_Name, CntLnameLen, CntFnameLen.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood the question, something like this might be what you're looking for.

```
select length(first_name), 
       length(last_name),
       count(*)
from members
group by length(first_name), 
         length(last_name);
```